# Debugging error when enabling Event Scheduler

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to set up IDE (PHPStorm) to use schema Introspection. To do this I need to enable Event Scheduler. I used this script :

```sql
    SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Unfortunately I am getting an error :

> Event Scheduler: An error occurred when initializing system tables.
>   Disabling the Event Scheduler.

I am not sure how to debug this. The error message contains too little information for my knowledge. What cloud be the reason for failed initialization of system tables?
I am using `10.4.8-MariaDB`

Comment: Did you recently upgrade?  Did you run `mysql_upgrade`?

Comment: Nope. Using the same one for months. `mysql_upgrade` did solve the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run `mysql_upgrade` a second time.

https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-18788